# How to make one second timer with atmega8?

Tags: timer, avr, atmega

I want make a one second timer with atmega8 and timer0. I used 8Mhz crystal and `prescale = 1`. 
Every 125ns timer0 increases by one, so when timer0 overflows 31250 times, we should have one second, but it doesn't work properly and delays more then 5 seconds.
I used BascomAVR.

```
$regfile = "m8def.dat"
$crystal = 8000000
Config Lcd = 16 * 2
Config Lcdpin = Pin , Db4 = Portd.4 , Db5 = Portd.5 , Db6 = Portd.6 
,Db7 = Portd.7 , E = Portd.3 , Rs = Portd.2
Config Timer0 = Timer , Prescale = 1
Dim Second As Word , Minute As Word , Hour As Word , Z As Integer
Second = 0
Minute = 0
Hour = 0
Z = 0
Enable Interrupts
Enable Timer0
Enable Ovf0
On Ovf0 Ovfroutin
Timer0 = 0
Start Timer0
Cursor Off
Cls : Home
Lcd "00:00:00"
Do
Loop
End                                                         'end program

Ovfroutin:
  Incr Z
  If Z = 31250 Then
     Stop Timer0
     Z = 0
     Incr Second
     If Second = 60 Then
        Second = 0
        Incr Minute
        If Minute = 60 Then
           Minute = 0
           Incr Hour
           If Hour = 24 Then
              Hour = 0
           End If
           If Hour < 10 Then
              Locate 1 , 1
              Lcd "0"
              Locate 1 , 2
           Else
              Locate 1 , 1
           End If
           Lcd Hour
        End If
        If Minute < 10 Then
           Locate 1 , 4
           Lcd "0"
           Locate 1 , 5
        Else
           Locate 1 , 4
        End If
        Lcd Minute
     End If
     If Second < 10 Then
        Locate 1 , 7
        Lcd "0"
        Locate 1 , 8
     Else
        Locate 1 , 7
     End If
     Lcd Second
     Start Timer0
  End If
  Timer0 = 0
Return
```

Comment: Are you sure your controller is running on external crystal and not on internal 1MHz RC? What does "delays more then 5 seconds" mean? How long exactly? Is it exactly periodic?

Comment: What are your fuse bits set to?  One of the fuses divides the clock by 8.